# How do I do a third person camera in the Game Engine?

Tags: game-engine, camera

I've had problems with getting a third person camera to rotate correctly. I've tried taking first person camera python scripts and modifying them, as well as third person camera scripts already on the internet, and No matter what, they always rotate around the original position of the character, so when I move the character it will be able to move around like moving an object out from a rotating disk, if that makes any sense. Any help I could get with changing the rotation position would be great. Thanks.

EDIT: Nevermind, figured it out. If anyone is having the same problem, let me know and I'll put my answer.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer, sometime it will be useful when others try to find it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the problem was in the script I was using. You can find it here: riyusakisan.weebly.com
In this bit of code here:

`Mouselook Properties
ml{
    ### Basic Properties ###
    (num) sensitivity = 3
    (bool) invert = false
    (bool) inherit = true`

Turning "inherit" to false will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Third Person Camera - Made by Mobious

import bge
import math
import mathutils as mathu

# constants
# Feel free to tweak these.
SENSITIVITY = .003      # mouse sensitivity
S = .8                  # mouse smoothing
INV_X = 1               # invert x-axis
INV_Y = 1               # invert y-axis
MAX_DIST = 25.0         # maximum distance from player
MIN_DIST = 5            # minimum distance to obstacle or player
DRCAP = .5              # distance restore speed cap
RSMOOTH = 20            # camera range smoothing
FSMOOTH = RSMOOTH / 3   # front obstruction smoothing
ZSMOOTH = 13            # zoom smoothing
LRSMOOTH = 10           # camera LR smoothing
ZOOM_STEP = 1.3         # distance to zoom on mousewheel
Z_OFFSET = 1.0          # Z offset from player
HOR_OFFSET = 80.0        # Horizontal offset factor
MIN_ANGLE = math.pi/20  # minimum angle camera can be from verticle
PROP = 'block_camera'   # property that block camera

# Change 'Player' to whatever object you want the camera to track
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
player = scene.objects['Player']

# controls
ZoomIn = bge.events.WHEELUPMOUSE
ZoomOut = bge.events.WHEELDOWNMOUSE
ToggleLR = bge.events.MIDDLEMOUSE

def main():

    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner

    mouse = cont.sensors['Mouse']
    rear = cont.sensors['rear']
    front = cont.sensors['front']

    # initialize vars
    if 'x' not in own:
        own['x'] = 0.0
        own['y'] = math.pi / 3
        own['dist'] = MAX_DIST
        x = bge.render.getWindowWidth() // 2
        y = bge.render.getWindowHeight() // 2
        own['size'] = (x,y)
        bge.render.setMousePosition(x,y)
        own['zoom'] = MAX_DIST
        own['oldx'] = 0.0
        own['oldy'] = 0.0
        rear.range = MAX_DIST
        front.range = MAX_DIST - MIN_DIST
        rear.propName = PROP
        front.propName = PROP
        own['LR'] = HOR_OFFSET
        own['LRinv'] = 1
        return

    # check and correct for camera obstructions using smoothing
    # obstacle in front of camera
    if front.positive:
        dist = own.getDistanceTo(front.hitPosition)
        if (own['dist'] - dist) > MIN_DIST:
            own['dist'] -= (dist + MIN_DIST) / FSMOOTH

    # obstacle behind camera
    elif rear.positive:
        dist = own.getDistanceTo(rear.hitPosition)
        if dist > MIN_DIST:
            if own['dist'] - own['zoom'] < 0:
                own['dist'] += (dist - min(MIN_DIST, own['zoom'])) / RSMOOTH
        elif own.getDistanceTo(player) > MIN_DIST:
            own['dist'] -= min(MIN_DIST - dist, own['dist'] - MIN_DIST) / RSMOOTH
    elif own['dist'] < own['zoom']: # restore max distance
        dist = (own['zoom'] - own['dist'])
        own['dist'] += dist / ZSMOOTH
    if own['dist'] > own['zoom']: # zoom in
        own['dist'] -= (own['dist'] - own['zoom']) / ZSMOOTH
    front.range = own['dist'] - MIN_DIST

    # mouse movement
    xpos = own['size'][0]
    ypos = own['size'][1]
    x = INV_X*(xpos - mouse.position[0])
    y = -INV_Y*(ypos - mouse.position[1])
    x *= SENSITIVITY
    y *= SENSITIVITY

    # smooth movement
    own['oldx'] = (own['oldx']*S + x*(1-S))
    own['oldy'] = (own['oldy']*S + y*(1-S))
    x = own['oldx']
    y = own['oldy']

    # center mouse in game window
    bge.render.setMousePosition(xpos,ypos)

    # zoom controls
    keys = bge.logic.mouse.events
    keys.update(bge.logic.keyboard.events)
    if keys[ZoomIn] and own['zoom'] >= MIN_DIST + ZOOM_STEP:
        own['zoom'] -= ZOOM_STEP
    elif keys[ZoomOut] and own['zoom'] <= MAX_DIST - ZOOM_STEP:
        own['zoom'] += ZOOM_STEP

    # update angles
    inv = False
    own['x'] += x
    own['y'] -= y

    if own['x'] > math.pi:
        own['x'] -= 2*math.pi
        inv = True
    elif own['x'] <= -2*math.pi:
        own['x'] += 2*math.pi
        inv = True
    if own['y'] > math.pi - 2*MIN_ANGLE:
        own['y'] = math.pi - 2*MIN_ANGLE
    elif own['y'] < 0.0 + MIN_ANGLE:
        own['y'] = 0.0 + MIN_ANGLE

    # LR toggling and smoothing
    if keys[ToggleLR] == 1:
        own['LRinv'] *= -1
    dist = own['LRinv']*HOR_OFFSET - own['LR']
    own['LR'] += dist / LRSMOOTH
    dist = own['LR'] / math.pow(own['dist'], 2)

    # calculate and set new camera position
    own['tdist'] = own['dist']*math.fabs(math.cos(math.pi/2 - own['y']))
    zshift = own['dist']*math.sin(math.pi/2 - own['y'])
    z = player.worldPosition[2] + zshift + Z_OFFSET
    yshift = own['tdist']*-math.cos(own['x'])
    y = player.worldPosition[1] + yshift + dist*math.sin(own['x'])
    xshift = own['tdist']*math.sin(own['x'])
    x = player.worldPosition[0] + xshift + dist*math.cos(own['x'])
    own.worldPosition = [x,y,z]

    #set new camera angle
    vec = mathu.Vector((own['y'], 0, own['x']))
    own.localOrientation = vec
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more explanation, other than just posting the code?